# Remote Administer Local Groups with PowerShell and WMI

Tags: powershell, wmi, groups, remote-access

How do I administer local groups on a remote server with PowerShell and WMI? For example, I would like to add and remove domain AD groups from the "Remote Desktop Users" group.

[This article](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-remote-machine-members-bc5faa57) provides a script for listing users while [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176860.aspx) provides a bit more detail on the Get-WMIObject (GWMI) and Set-WMIObject (SWMI) cmdlets, however I'm unsure how to proceed with updating the group membership.

Comment: as a starting point for this type of question go to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/bb410849.aspx.

Comment: And why are we using WMI/Powershell instead of GPOs/GPPs?

Comment: @HopelessN00b good point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADSI is your friend

```
$server = "somesServer"
$domain = "someDomain
$group2add = "group2add"
$localGroup = [adsi]"WinNT://$server/administrators,group"
$domainGroup = [adsi]"WinNT://$domain/$group2add,group"
$localGroup.Add($domainGroup.path)
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I also worked out how to list the members from this:

`$localmembers = @($localGroup.psbase.Invoke("Members"))
$localmembers | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("AdsPath","GetProperty",$null,$_,$null)}`